# How do you properly put your published work in to your PhD thesis?

Tags: phd, thesis, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

I have previously published a couple of papers in my PhD. I want to put them into my PhD. thesis as is. Is there any proper way to include the papers without doing any self-plagiarism?

Comment: Some institutions allow this practice and others do not.  Most journals will give you permission to reuse your published papers but others will not.  The answer to your question depends very much on the particular policies of your institution and the journals you have published in.  Thus we can’t answer your question.